# my website address with www redirects to a different page

Tags: wordpress, vps

[image]I hosted a website (chameleonlabs.org)  using AApanel and WordPress on oracle cloud free tier vps.
I am able to access the website using "https://chameleonlabs.org/".
But when I use "https://www.chameleonlabs.org/" and "http://www.chameleonlabs.org/" addresses it is redirected to different pages.

Comment: ServerFault maybe a better site to ask this on. Also, include the detail, what actually happens. "Different pages" tells us nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the DNS records for the site are correct?

For example, you might want

A * SERVER_IP
A www SERVER_IP

at the very least

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of my DNS records  please have look and let me know